# My app crashes at startup due to missing libpq_cust.so lib

Tags: android-ndk

our app works fine on most of the android 7 devices. However on one brand Geotel A1 device, the app crashes at startup throwing the following error:

```
08-25 15:18:47.728  7443  7509 E linker  : library "libpq_cust.so" ("/system/vendor/lib/libpq_cust.so") needed or dlopened by "/system/vendor/lib/libpq_prot.so" is not accessible for the namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="/data/app/com.xyz.pay-1/lib/arm:/system/fake-libs:/data/app/com.xyz.pay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi", permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand:/data/data/com.xyz.pay"]
    08-25 15:18:49.978   957  1008 E InputDispatcher: channel '69f4912 com.xyz.pay/com.xyz.cac.start.authorizationActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

I have included the other libs such as libandroid_runtime.so, libcutils.so, libcrypto.so, and libssl.so in to the apk.

However, I dont know from where I can get this file libpq_cust.so. Can some one pls help me in solving this issue?

Comment: I have tried with several libq_cust.so files found on the web but is of no use. app still crashes.

Comment: your help is highly appreciated!!